# Как найти значения из масива alarms[ ] по id?

Tags: javascript, json, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть id события, я хочу найти в каком из элементов массива есть этот id...
Например: у меня есть `id:"8ddd11b0-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e"`, как мне узнать в каком элементе массива есть такой id, в 600 или в 601 и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так найти элемент:

```
let id = "8ddd11b0-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e";
let alarm = <имя объекта>.defaultSubscription.alarms.find(object => object.originator.id === id);
let alarmId = alarm ? alarm.originator.id : null;
```